# How do repeated downloads in the iOS App Store and/or Google Play Store count?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

My question is for how downloads by a user who already had the app installed previously (but deleted it) get counted. Does each repeated download count towards the daily download numbers relevant for ranking in the app charts or can one user only contribute to this statistic once (on the first download)?

So basically does the following procedure count as one download or n downloads for determining the ranking in the iOS App Store and Google Play Store Charts?:

```
user downloads app for the first time
do n times:
   delete app
   download app again
```

Comment: 1/ Two thoughts? 1) Look at this as a user instead of a developer. If you *delete* any app and then go to Apple's AppStore, you get a download link/button instead of a purchase one. 2) Purchases for an app **are** complete - sans IAP - once done. If you purchased my app for $0.99US today and wish to download/install/whatever on that same Apple ID to that device after installing (or any other device that uses the *same* Apple ID), you can **at no cost**.

Comment: 2/ Final thought. With the above being what is, well what **is** your question? Gaming the store rankings? I'll give you the benefit of the doubt - that you are more concerned about getting your app ranked instead of gaming it. Again two thoughts! 1) Look at this from a developer perspective. Why do you care? Just build the best app you can and see if someone else agrees! 2) Now look at this from the store's perspective. You simply **do not** want anyone to "game" things. So you will do your best to not have those techniques influence rankings. Including install/delete bots.

Comment: @Philipp Think about how we (other than insiders) can know Google or Apple's ranking algorithm?

Comment: I asked myself this question because I read about some Single Life Games (where you have only one life, so when you die you're done with the app). So one of my first thoughts about them was whether users redownloading the app in order to play again would increase the ranking and help going viral. Obviously it's not gonna help if the app is shitty in general, totally agree on that one. The Answer makes sense and I also expected it to be like this, just wanted to check whether someone knows this for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS app download statistics in App Store Connect reflect only the sale of app units. If the user deletes the app and redownloads it, it does not increase the number of downloads. Users who download the app on multiple devices are still only counted as one download since only one unit was sold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My upvote won't show though because I am a newbie here and have less than 15 reputation :D.